# I can't import pygame inside pycharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, linux-mint

I can't import `pygame` inside `pycharm`.
I've been using Linux Mint 19, Anaconda 3, Pycharm 2019.3.1.
I've created a conda environment and install pygame: `conda install pygame -c cogsci`
Then I ran `(my_env) tiago@tiago-XPS-8700:~$ python3 mycode.py`. And I got the following error:

> teste.py:3: RuntimeWarning: use mixer: libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory (ImportError:
>   libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)   pygame.mixer.music.load('bat.mp3') Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "teste.py", line 3, in 
>       pygame.mixer.music.load('bat.mp3')   File "/home/tiago/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py",
>   line 105, in **getattr**
>       raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule) NotImplementedError: mixer module not available (ImportError:
>   libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory)

After reading some blog at internet I installed `sudo apt install libsdl-mixer1.2`.
After that if I run `(my_env) tiago@tiago-XPS-8700:~$ python3 mycode.py` at Linux terminal at my conda environment, my code run successfully.
But If I try to run the same code inside `Pycharm` I get the following error:

> /home/tiago/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/bin/python
>   /home/tiago/Documentos/PYTHON/cursoemvideo/exercicios/ex_021.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/tiago/Documentos/PYTHON/cursoemvideo/exercicios/ex_021.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import pygame   File "/home/tiago/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py",
>   line 133, in 
>       from pygame.base import * ImportError: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In conda environment  they have pre installed packages and libraries which u can easily use by importing them but in pycharm u additionally need to intall that package so that u can use it in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this questions [Tensorflow and Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020050/tensorflow-and-pycharm), I ran Pychram from the Linux Terminal at my conda environment and it worked! If I run Pycharm from Linux Mint Menu I still can't import `pygame`.
Addicionally, I inserted the following statement at my `.bashrc` so that I can run pycharm from anywhere in the Linux Terminal.

```
# Open bashrc to edit
nano .bashrc

# Add the comand line below to the end of file
# You should adapt to your path to "pycharm.sh', mine is "/opt/pycharm-community-anaconda-2019.1.3/bin". In another computer I found it at "/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/current/active/files/pycharm/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/pycharm-community-anaconda-2019.1.3/bin

# Then close the terminal and reopen it in order to the modifications in .bashrc take effect
# At terminal you run
pycharm.sh
```